# has many didn't work with my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

I'm trying to get my has_many working.

I've two models:

project:

- name:string
- desc:text
- tags:references

project has_many :tags

tags:

- name:string

tags belongs_to :project

my project_controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.tags = Tags.new
end
```

but what is the right view?
I tried something like this:

```
= form_for @project do |f|
 = f.text_field :title
 = f.text_area :desc

 = f.fields_for :tags, @project.tags do |f_tags|
   = f_tags.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Tag-Name'
```

But I get a error like this:
undefined method 'name' for #`<Tag::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f4456cc7148>`

I didn't get my mistake.

And how I can add multiple tags? 
My idea was to duplicate the div where the tag are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call `build` on your tags relation, and then not pass tag objects to your `fields_for`.

Controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.tags.build
end
```

View:

```
= f.fields_for :tags do |f_tags|
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. But how can I use it for multiple Tags?

Comment: `2.times { @project.tags.build }` will build two tags for you.